# How to assign types in php without causing parse errors?

Tags: php, class

```
class SubheaderPresenter {
  private string $titletag;
  private string $alignment;
  private bool   $displaySubheader;
  private string $Visibility;
  private string $output;
}
```

whenever i add type to properties, i get this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'string' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)
```

It seems like assigning the types to these properties causing the error. What can i do to fix it. php does support types right? ( just started learning it yesterday )

Comment: *As of PHP 7.4.0, property definitions can include a type declaration, with the exception of the callable type.*, so do you know what version of PHP you are using?

Comment: php 7.3.18 @NigelRen